# Картинка из HTML

Tags: jquery, php, html

Привет всем.столкнулся с необычной задачей для себя. Нужно из страницы сайта из верстки сделать изображение с помощью PHP я думаю этот вопрос решаем только не знаю с какой стороны подойти кто сталкивался с подобным подскажите быстрое решение проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php
2. http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ — работает на клиенте
3. http://phantomjs.org/ — [пример работы](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/technews.js), но это node.js

Comment: Тоесть функция imagegrabscreen это и есть решение проблемы ??

Comment: Нет, почитайте вочитайте внимательно, там подробно расписано + Note, these functions are available on Windows systems ONLY! Решение на php, это [генерация pdf][1] на основе хтмл и конвертация pdf в png. Я бы запустил PhantomJS из php и сделал скрин.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php#757778

Comment: Функция доступна только в Windows. А есть какие либо решения на серверной стороне ?? тоесть допустим пишу скрипт отправки письма и мне нужно сделать автоматом скрин какой либо страницы и приложить его в письмо

Comment: Ответил же выше. Если бы мне пришлось делать такое, воспользовался бы для этих целей PhantomJS, который бы запускал из php.

Comment: Спасибо направление ясно буду делать )))